# how to make your ITNewServiceRequest page show data from the new table ITNewServiceRequestTest instead of the old table ITNewServiceRequest,

Tags: c#

okay i have a ITNewServiceRequest page..and it straight goes or shows ITNewServiceRequest in database....now i set a new table in database where the name is ITNewServiceRequestTest..So now i want the ITNewServiceRequest page to show the new table.how to do it?

i changed to test..but it still won't show in database..which means it can't retrieve data to test table

Comment: I think it would probably be challenging for any question to be more ambiguous than this one. It's extremely unclear what you're doing, what you're trying to achieve, and what problems you actually have here.

Comment: okay i have ITNewServiceRequest page..and it straight show ITNewServiceRequest in database....now i set a new table in database where the name is ITNewServiceRequestTest..So now i want the code in ITNewServiceRequest page to show in the new table.........how to do it?can you understand?

Comment: That's not any clearer. One obvious question: what is a "page"? And another: If you can show "ITNewServiceRequest", what is the problem with showing "ITNewServiceRequestTest"? What is the core of your actual question here? Are you asking how to change the data source for some "page", or something else?

Comment: okay im doing a webform..part of the webform is ITNewServiceRequest..now i have 2 tables on my database ...so now if i click submit button on ITNewServiceRequest , it will show in the ITNewServiceRequest table..but i want it to show on ITNewServiceRequestTest table..

Comment: So your code to save is saving to the wrong table?

Comment: yes...and i want it to save in ITNewServiceRequestTest table not in ITNewServiceRequest table.

Comment: You should edit your question, show your current code, and make a clearer statement about what you're trying to do, and what's preventing you from doing that. Note that your code must be posted as text.

Comment: but i can't show my code....

Comment: Why not? Anyway, we need a [mcve], we don't need your exact code. As long as your [mcve] demonstrates the same problem for the same reasons as your actual code, it's fine. At the moment, I can't picture how all your stuff goes together that simply changing a string value "ITNewsServiceRequest" to "ITNewServiceRequestTest" isn't the solution. It's impossible to help you when we don't understand how you're doing things, and there's SO MANY ways of doing things.

Comment: Well I fully agree with Llama here: We need more details/code. The only thing I could picture rn is that MAYBE in the Method where you wanna save to the second table, which I assume you copypasted from your first Method, you didnt change the nececary things in that method? Like we need a bit more from you

Comment: So when you are talking about a "page" do you mean its something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: Please read [ask], and also consider the possibility that we can't see your screen or read your mind. Then [edit] your question with some relevant code and data so we have some idea what you are actually talking about. It's not clear why you won't show your code - I doubt it contains any commercial or state secrets, somehow... We'd love to help you, but please be realistic and realise that nobody can fix badly-described problems occurring in code they have never seen. It's similar to the way you would expect that your mechanic can't fix your car if you don't take it to the repair shop!